# Processing: conditional to test for variable change

Tags: variables, conditional-statements, processing

My question pertains to the environment of `Processing 2.0.`

I need to write a conditional (or set of conditionals) in `void draw()` that tests if the variable `x` has increased by 1 or decreased by 1 and adjust the variable `y` depending on the increase/decrease in `x`. For example if `x` decreases 1, `y` should increase by 10, and if `x` increases by 1 `y` should decrease by 10. How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

The most obvious answer is to try to think of **y** as a multiple of **x** plus maybe an offset? So if you have your **x** going up and down every time you enter the draw() method you should do `y = x * 10;` or `y = 400 + x * 10` if you have an offset (int this case 400) of some sorts...

If you absolutely have to do it like that, then the way is to store the previous value of x and check each at each draw() call. So create a new variable `int prevX` and in your draw() method do:

```
y = y + (x-prevX) * 10;
```

or

```
int diff = x - prevX;
if(diff == -1) y = y - 10;
else if (diff == 1) y = y + 10;
```